# remove nicEdit instance from a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, nicedit

What seems like a nice simple solution is being a right pain in the backside.

I have a DIV with in my example an id of element_105.  When you click the DIV the nicEdit wysiwyg is applied to the DIV (even though nicEdit looks to be not worked on anymore I like its featueres.  It allows me to turn a div not a textarea into an editable box.).

So far so go.  However I want to able to remove the nicEdit instance from the div when you click a link or blur from the div.  In the real application I have more than one div on which I want to click to and apply the nicEdit wsyiwyg and remove it when the user clicks the next div or off the div they were editing.

To make this easier to understand Ive provided a JSFiddle to show my current trials.

http://jsfiddle.net/8eLQW/32/

Comment: Im also open to suggestions to a better wysiwyg edit that is relativly simple.  CKeditor, timymce seem a bit much for my needs.  However if anyone can just show me how to get the nicEdit to dissappear off the div Id be very greatful.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late but I just bumped into the same problem and finally figured it out.

It's a NicEdit bug. The removeInstance() works on `<textarea>`s only.

http://jsfiddle.net/8eLQW/41/

Not that it helps you but still... I thought It wouldn't hurt letting you know :)